# set environment variables when KDE is starting using source (using Intel Compilers under Kate)

Tags: kde, kate

I'm trying to use the Intel compilers in Kate's build plugin. The recommended way from Intel is to source the compilevars.sh scripts, using

```
# source <path_to_intel>/compilevars.sh intel64
```

It works fine if I source this file from my `.bashrc`. If I use the KDE way of sourcing a file when the session starts, indicated [here](https://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables), the script runs correctly and executes but the Intel compilers are not put in the path.

What is the proper way of sourcing the Intel scripts?